# Is it possible to make a custom Gravity.Right method for Edittext?

Tags: android

In my app quote/poem writing app, the user should be able to place the text either on right or left side.

This can ofcourse be archived with `mEditText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.LEFT);`

But the problem is that the text is placed to left without any space and it dosn't look good. What I want is better explained with this image:

Shall this be archived with some sort of a custom Gravity.Right/Left method if it is possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `android:paddingLeft` and `android:paddingRight` to add additional space on left and right edge of TextView

[image]

Comment: Oh! Thanks man. That did exactly like I wanted. Sometimes solutions is just to simple to think of it!

Answer (score 0):

I'd put some left padding on the view instead.  That will give you the same effect, without the effort.